# Resample datetime - Error: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-resample

Would you help me with the following error:

ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit

Let's say I have a dataframe df

```
datetime                   A      B      C
2020-07-02 23:00:01    50     nan    nan
2020-07-02 23:00:02    nan    60     nan
2020-07-02 23:00:11    nan    nan    80
2020-07-02 23:14:01    nan    nan    65
2020-07-02 23:15:01    nan    90     nan
2020-07-02 23:15:02    10     nan    nan
2020-07-02 23:28:01    20     25     nan
2020-07-02 23:30:01    nan    nan    80
```

What I am trying to achieve is the following output:

```
datetime                   A      B      C
2020-07-02 23:00:00    50     60    80
2020-07-02 23:15:00    10    90    65
2020-07-02 23:30:01    20    25    80
```

I tried this with the following code:

```
df.datetime = pd.to_datetime(dfinal.datetime)
resampledata = df.set_index("tijd").resample("15T").pad()
```

But I got an error probably due to not having unique datetime values.

Comment: related: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/69304871/10197418

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your dataframe called `df`, use [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html)

```py
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df.set_index('datetime').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15min')).sum()
```

The output will be:

```markdown
| datetime            |   A |   B |   C |
|:--------------------|----:|----:|----:|
| 2020-07-02 23:00:00 |  50 |  60 | 145 |
| 2020-07-02 23:15:00 |  30 | 115 |   0 |
| 2020-07-02 23:30:00 |   0 |   0 |  80 |
```

Of course, you can change the range as you wish

Comment: `df.resample("15T").sum()` works similarly; the point is using an aggregator like sum, not just pad as the OP does in the example